# Error with roslaunch in remote machine

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am try to launch my setup remotely. This is my launch file:

```
<launch>

  <machine name="auriga" address="192.168.1.103" user="auriga" />
  <machine name="local"  address="localhost" />
 
  <param name="robot_description"     textfile="$(find auriga_model)/auriga_robot_box.urdf" />

  <node  name="laser_hokuyo"          pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" machine="auriga" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <param name="calibrate_time"      type="bool"       value="false" />            <!-- Starts up faster, but timestamps will be inaccurate. -->
    <param name="port"                type="string"     value="/dev/ttyACM0" />     <!-- Set the port to connect to here -->
    <param name="intensity"           type="bool"       value="false" />
    <param name="min_ang"             type="double"     value="-2.08621" />
    <param name="max_ang"             type="double"     value="+2.08621" />
  </node>

    <node  name="laser_broadcaster"     pkg="tf"                    type="static_transform_publisher" machine="auriga" args="0 0 0.73 0 0 0 base_link laser 50" />
    <node  name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher"            machine="auriga" />
    <node  name="visualization"         pkg="rviz"                  type="rviz"                       machine="local"/>

</launch>
```

And I get the following output:

```
... logging to /home/jose/.ros/log/0db3bbbc-651b-11e0-ad9f-00032d122e94/roslaunch-RoboIcaro-2938.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://RoboIcaro:34567/
remote[192.168.1.103-0] starting roslaunch
remote[192.168.1.103-0]: creating ssh connection to 192.168.1.103:22, user[auriga]
remote[192.168.1.103-0]: ssh connection created
remote[192.168.1.103-0]: Exception while registering with roslaunch parent [http://RoboIcaro:34567/]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/server.py", line 489, in _register_with_server
    code, msg, _ = server.register(name, self.uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1199, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1489, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1235, in request
    self.send_content(h, request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1349, in send_content
    connection.endheaders()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 904, in endheaders
    self._send_output()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 776, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 735, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 716, in connect
    self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 500, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known


[192.168.1.103-0] process has died
remote roslaunch failed to launch: auriga
```

May it be a bug?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9707/error-with-roslaunch-in-remote-machine/) by [jsogorb](https://answers.ros.org/users/372/jsogorb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2011-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a bug that it's not caught, but it also means your network is not configured properly.  It's important that you have a proper network setup if you intend to use ROS with remote machines.

In this case, RoboIcaro is not a valid hostname, which is why roslaunch is raising an exception.

Please read: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup

for a guide on how to test your network config.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jsogorb](https://answers.ros.org/users/372/jsogorb/) on 2011-04-12**:
Thank you, after configure the network everything works fine.